# Using reference rows within different groups in a DataFrame to perform data manipulations

Tags: python, pandas

Given this DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'b', 4: 'c', 5: 'c', 6: 'd', 7: 'd'},
'Time': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 1},
'Mean': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 5, 4: 2, 5: 6, 6: 2, 7: 9}})
```

For each group in the DataFrame (`a` and `b`), I would like to take each number in the `Mean` column and divide it by the corresponding value at `Time == 0`, and take the `np.log2` of this. In other words, I want to end up with this

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'b', 4: 'c', 5: 'c', 6: 'd', 7: 'd'},
 'Time': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 0, 7: 1},
 'Mean': {0: 1, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 5, 4: 2, 5: 6, 6: 2, 7: 9},
 'New': {0: 0.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 2.321928094887362, 4: 0.0, 5: 1.584962500721156, 6: 0.0, 7: 2.169925001442312}})
```

Currently I achieved this in the following way

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for group, sub in df.groupby('Group'):
    sub['New'] = np.log2(sub.Mean / sub.Mean.iloc[0])
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, sub], axis=0)
```

But I feel like there should be a simpler way.

Comment: Seems like there's the implicit assumption in your code that `Time == 0` is the first row within the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `groupby` with transform `first`(to substitute `iloc[0]`) and then divide with the `Mean` column.

```
df['New'] = np.log2(df['Mean']/df.groupby("Group")['Mean'].transform('first'))
```

---

```
  Group  Time  Mean       New
0     a     0     1  0.000000
1     a     1     4  2.000000
2     b     0     1  0.000000
3     b     1     5  2.321928
4     c     0     2  0.000000
5     c     1     6  1.584963
6     d     0     2  0.000000
7     d     1     9  2.169925
```

EDIT:

You can also do the below if you are not sure of the index where the Time equals 0:

```
df['New'] = (np.log2(df['Mean']/df.loc[df['Time'].eq(0).groupby(df['Group'])
               .transform('idxmax'),'Mean'].to_numpy()))
```

This will for each group return the max index when the cond Time=0 is True. , then using `df.loc` we return the Mean Column and use it for division. For more information see how [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) works

---

```
print(df)

  Group  Time  Mean       New
0     a     0     1  0.000000
1     a     1     4  2.000000
2     b     0     1  0.000000
3     b     1     5  2.321928
4     c     0     2  0.000000
5     c     1     6  1.584963
6     d     0     2  0.000000
7     d     1     9  2.169925
```

Comment: If I instead of using the *first* element of each group, I wanted to explicitly use the row for which `Time == 0`. Is there a way to do that? For instance if I have multiple replicate measurements as individual rows in the long-form DataFrame.

Comment: This will take some time to de-construct :) Much obliged! I can modify the Q, and perhaps you can add this with a short explanation to the answer?

Comment: @Yoda I appreciate you asking before changing the question :) I have added some explanation, let me know if that is unclear and I will try and edit further..!!

Comment: Using `.transform('idxmax')` gave different results than simply `.idxmax()` on the groupby object. using the idxmax function only returned the unique values, whereas the transform returned a series with the same number of rows as the input dataframe.

Comment: @Yoda thats the idea, since we are dividing a dataframe we cant do the same with an aggregated dataframe(groupby.idxmax), hence we used transform to broadcast the idxmax for each group, so that we can use loc to return duplicated Mean values (for each group where the condition suffices) and we can divide , (to_numpy is for converting this to np array since pandas divides based on indexes)